# How to customize Views in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have started working on Odoo 10 recently. I need to customize form and tree views.

For example

1. Open a new form view when clicking on a button in a tree view.
2. Also, I want a different form view which comes as a result of saved record.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please update your question with attempt code.

Answer (score 3):

> > Hello this answer is for your first case that is ***Open a new form
> >     view when clicking on a button in tree view***
>
> ```
> Try returning something like this - 
> Calling method on button click
> ```

```
@api.multi
def my_method(self):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'model_name',
        'view_type': 'form', #to redirect to form view
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, this answer is for your Second case that is ***you also want a
>   different form view which comes as a result of saved record.***

```
@api.multi
def my_method(self):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'model_name',
        'view_type': 'form', #to redirect to form view
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': record.id
    }
```